# Summing triplets in C

Tags: c

Okay so I have a file with a bunch of digits

```
002003005\n
001001\n
```

and I want to sum all the digits by three so the first lines sum would be 10 and the second line would be 2. Right now I'm not sure whats wrong with my control flow

```
#define MAXLINE 1000
int counter = 0;
int inputLine[MAXLINE] = {0};
int main(void)
{
  int sum = 0;
  int i = 0;
  int ii = 0;
  char c;
  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
  {
    if (c == '\n')
    {
      for (ii = 0; ii < counter; ii = ii + 3)
      {
        sum = sum + ((inputLine[ii] - '0') * 100) + ((inputLine[ii+1] - '0') * 10) + ((inputLine[ii+2] - '0') * 1);
      }
      printf("%d\n", sum);
      sum = 0;
      counter = 0;
    }

    inputLine[i] = c;
    i++;
    counter++;
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not resetting `i` when you reach the end of a line.

Insert:

```
i = 0;
```

After the `counter = 0` line.

You also need to include this block:

```
inputLine[i] = c;
i++;
counter++;
```

Within an `else`, since it shouldn't happen for the carriage return at the end of each line.

Once you've done that, you'll (hopefully) notice that `i` and `counter` will always contain the same value on each pass through the loop, so there's no need for them both to exist.

Comment: maybe `counter` was meant to count the lines? in that case OP would move `counter++` to where `counter = 0` is inside the `if`.

Comment: Also, initializing i to the same value just before the loop and after every iteration sounds redundant - do it once in the beggining of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If your `char` type is `unsigned` by default then your end condition is not good

```
char c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

You should declare c as `int`, as `EOF` cannot be represented in the value range of 0..255. `EOF` is by definition a negative integer of type `int` used to indicate end-of-file conditions.